# Can I use if statement in constraint function for optimization using ga in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, optimization, constraints, genetic-algorithm

I have a constraint functions which call another function(inverse_kinematics) for calculating some of the constraints, inverse_kinematics() will give error if c(1) and c(2) are not satisfied, how can I ensure that c(1) and c(2) are satisfied before calling inverse_kinematics() function? Can I address it by using if condition in my constraint function? Below is code of my optimization function,

```
function [c, ceq] = simple_constraint(l1,l2,l3)

c(1) = l3^2 + 200*l3*cos(30) + 10000 - (l1 + l2)^2;
c(2) = (100- l3*cos(30))^2 + (100*sin(30))^2 - (l1-l2)^2;

thetas = inverse_kinematics(l1,l2,l3); % Gives error when c(1) and c(2) are not satisfied

c(3) = thetas(4,1) - 160;
c(4) = thetas(4,2) - 160;
c(5) = thetas(4,3) - 160;
c(6) = 20 - thetas(4,1);
c(7) = 20 - thetas(4,2);
c(8) = 20 - thetas(4,3);
c(9) = thetas(5,1) - 340;
c(10) = thetas(5,2) - 340;
c(11) = thetas(5,3) - 340;
c(12) = 200 - thetas(5,1);
c(13) = 200 - thetas(5,2);
c(14) = 200 - thetas(5,3);
c(15) = thetas(6,1) - 340;
c(16) = thetas(6,2) - 340;
c(17) = thetas(6,3) - 340;
c(18) = 200 - thetas(6,1);
c(19) = 200 - thetas(6,2);
c(20) = 200 - thetas(6,3);
ceq = [];
end
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

You can check the constraint by using `try` and `catch`

For example

```
c(1) = l3^2 + 200*l3*cos(30) + 10000 - (l1 + l2)^2;
c(2) = (100- l3*cos(30))^2 + (100*sin(30))^2 - (l1-l2)^2;
    try
        thetas = inverse_kinematics(l1,l2,l3);
    catch
        warning('C1 and C2 is wrong'); % Or you can change any parameter here
    end
```

Comment: I am more concerned whether using try and catch, if would disturb the flow of genetic algorithm? and what values to be assigned to constraints from c(3) to c(20) when inverse_kinematics(l1,l2,l3) can't be calculated?

Comment: Well, that depends on the thing that you are implementing. You should put in catch some alternative solution in which the convergence of the optimization is guaranteed.

Comment: In other words, your problem is not programming problem, but rather conceptual problem if that what you are asking for. Mathematics stack exchange is the best to address this issue, I think.